# Access pinia store from routes file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I am building a breadcrumbs component with Vue 3, Vue Router, and Pinia. I use a `breadcrumbs` meta key on my routes with a `label` and `parent` attribute. The component generates an array by resolving the parent routes recursively using `router.resolve()` and then create the component markup from this array. I use a pinia store and I want to dynamically generate the `meta.label` property on my routes file using attributes stored in the pinia store.

If I import the pinia store on the routes file like this:

```js
// routes file
import { useRentalStore } from "@/stores/rentalStore";

const rentalStore = useRentalStore();

const routes = [
  // extract from routes array
  {
    path: ":equipment",
    name: "rental-show",
    component: ShowRentalView,
    meta: {
      breadcrumbs: {
        label: () => rentalStore.rental.label,
        parent: "rental-index",
      },
    },
  },
];
```

I get the following error: `"getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia? const pinia = createPinia()`

I tried passing the pinia instance from the main entrypoint `main.js`

```js
// main.js
const pinia = createPinia()
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)
app.use(router)
//...
export { pinia }

// routes file
import {pinia} from '@/main.js'

const rentalStore = useRentalStore(pinia);
```

But this still won't work. I used a similar approach in Vue 2 with Vuex and the above worked with Vuex but it is not working with Pinia.. The above returns the following error message: `Cannot access 'pinia' before initialization`.

Any idea how to access the pinia store from the routes file? The pinia docs recommend to defer calls of useStore() by placing them inside functions that will always run after pinia is installed, but the parent route component will not run when the child component navigation is active.

Comment: You need to have created the `pinia` object before initializing the router. Otherwise it's a bit of a circular dependency of the main file importing the router, which imports the main file... I use a separate file for it, in my `stores` directory. Should I write up a full answer?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes yes if you don't mind please. I also tried to compute the label inside the `showRentalView` component and exposing the computed property to the routes file but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pinia creates store functions instead of store instances in order to avoid early instantiation. When used outside a component, `useRentalStore` should be called in a place where a store is used:

```
...
label: () => useRentalStore().rental.label,
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to get access to the store, however the stored object is blank and apparently not reactive.. the store makes an API to my backend to get the data but the `label: () => useRentalStore().rental.label` call does not update with the new data.

Comment: This depends from your case and how you use meta.label. Proceed from the fact that it's reactive and you need to wrap it with a computed or so. In 3.3 there's https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#tovalue to handle this case, so there should be `let label = toValue(meta.label)` somewhere

Comment: thanks, I seem to have some other issue with my store.. If I navigate to the component thru a router-link the label populates correctly, but if I hard refresh the label does not refresh with the new data from the API call.

Comment: API call? This sounds like there's a lot more going on. You could probably ask another question about that.

Comment: @enriqg9 Consider posting it in a new question if the problem persists. Generally this wouldn't be a problem with the approach in the comment above, also you'd like to finish an action that a route depends on before navigation end, so you wouldn't have this kind of race condition

Comment: I believe the issue is when I loop thru each parent component, then save the label into a `data.breadcrumbs` reactive array with unshift `data.breadcrumbs.unshift()`. But yes I will keep playing with it and post a new question if needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Notice: use the approach from the section at the end instead of actually *using* this approach. It is for explanation only, and should only be used when there is no other/better way.

You need to have created the `pinia` object before initializing the router. Otherwise there's a bit of a circular dependency of the main file importing the router, which imports the main file...

The solution is to use a separate file for initializing Pinia, and import that. The best is probably as the index file of the `stores` directory. For example, use this as `stores/index.js`:

```js
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

const pinia = createPinia();

export default pinia;
```

(This also provides a contained location to apply Pinia plugins, if you use any.)

Then, in your router file, import the Pinia instance from this and pass it to the store function:

```js
import pinia from "@/stores";
import { useRentalStore } from "@/stores/rentalStore";

const rentalStore = useRentalStore(pinia);

// As before...
```

And, in your main file, import the Pinia instance and use that:

```js
// ...

import pinia from "@/stores";

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)
app.use(router)
```

---

Usually, this is an anti-pattern.

The better choice is to "use" the store where it is used.
For example:

```js
import { useRentalStore } from "@/stores/rentalStore";

const routes = [
  // extract from routes array
  {
    path: ":equipment",
    name: "rental-show",
    component: ShowRentalView,
    meta: {
      breadcrumbs: {
        label: () => useRentalStore().rental.label,
        parent: "rental-index",
      },
    },
  },
];
```

As long as the store function is called after the Pinia instance has been installed with `app.use(pinia)`, Pinia will automatically use that instance; it only needs to be passed in if the store function is called before the Pinia instance is installed.

The docs have a short section on this: [Using a store outside of a component | Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html).

Comment: The first approach will result in the listed error, `getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia`. The problem is that not just `createPinia()` but also `use(pinia)` needs to be executed prior to useRentalStore, this affects the way how modules need to be structured in an awkward way, that's why they ended up with store functions

Comment: @EstusFlask I thought I was using this exact pattern to solve this exact issue, but it I believe I actually didn't have the issue in the end but the cruft remained. However, I do stand by my claim (for now, anyway): passing the Pinia instance means it will work before `app.use(pinia)` is called.

Comment: This is working for me: `const store = useMyStore(pinia); console.log(store.foo); const app = createApp(App).use(pinia)`.

Comment: Overlooked the `useMyStore(pinia)` part, sorry, this is workable indeed, the ability to provide custom pinia instance is yet another reason for store functions. Also, the remark on Vue's inject() isn't precise, using it would prevent the use outside components, Pinia uses custom mechanism to associate pinia and vue app instances internally

Comment: @EstusFlask Ah, yes, I misunderstood the docs. I've updated the question. Thanks