# Register plugin inside custom component

Tags: vue.js

I want to use Vuex inside a vue custom component. I got NO access to the instantiation nor can I use a wrapper for defineCustomElement, so I need to register the plugin inside the root.ce.vue file. How would I do that? Simply using

```
import {
  useStore
} from 'vuex'
const store = useStore();
```

won't do cause I got no possibility to call `app.use(store)` before.
Could I import the store directly and use it as is?

Comment: Consider explaining your case in details, you describe some odd scenario that could be XY problem, the solution may depend on it. Since vuex is global state, it's presumed that it's set up globally in the app. Since this wasn't done, probably you don't need vuex at all for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @EstusFlask I need to use the custom component cause it's embededed in an existing app. There's just this component so I need the global store for it if users leave the page. So I wanted to know if there's a possibility in Vue3 to register the vuex plugin inside of the component. Cause the registration is generic and used for other custom components as well that don't need a store.

Comment: No, there's no official way, and I doubt it will work even if you hack into Vue in undocumented way because this happens after app has been initialized. Global store will keep data only for SPA until page reload, it's unknown if "users leave the page" is really applicable. I'm not sure why is it a problem that other comps don't need a store, it's registered for the whole app any way. You can try pinia for the same purpose as it's not strictly tied to vue app instance and can be used without app.use, see the first part of this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/77053572/3731501

Comment: And you may not need third-party store at all, https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api .