# Adding role based routes in vue router with pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, pinia

I want to load one of three possible routes depending on a users role in my pinia store. The current problem I'm having is that the pinia store doesn't seem to be initalised before the router has been set getting the error

`Uncaught Error: []: getActivePinia was called with no active`

is there a way for me to address this issue?

For reference the routes are set like

```
const roleOneRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('@/pages/RoleOne/Home'),
  },
  ...
]

const roleTwoRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('@/pages/RoleTwo/Home'),
  },
  ...
]
```

Then in the index file I would ideally want something similar

```
const { user } = useAuthStore()

const mappedRoutes = user.role === 'roleOne' ? roleOneRoutes : roleTwoRoutes

export const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: mappedRoutes
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinia store cannot be normally accessed at the top of a module, `useAuthStore` is a function and not an object because this allows to prevent eager access. It should be called in the place where store data is actually needed. In this case this would result in race condition because `user` is likely not set at this moment.

View component can be conditionally set like this:

```
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => useAuthStore().user.role === 'roleOne' 
      ? import('@/pages/RoleOne/Home')
      : import('@/pages/RoleTwo/Home')
  },
```

Comment: Is there not a way to delay until the pinia store is ready before the router is mounted? I would rather avoid having to conditionally check for each route like this and have a set of mapped routes for a given role. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to avoid importing routes module prior to that moment, not just initializing a router.  This is an awkward and unconventional way but it's possible, this will require dynamic imports and/or top-level await. Something like that, see this answer for this kind of pinia usage https://stackoverflow.com/a/77053572/3731501 . It would be like  `let store = useAuthStore(pinia); await store.initUsers(); const mappedRoutes =...` . A user won't be able to relogin this way, this would require to reload the page. As said, it's awkward.

Comment: I'd rather suggest to write a helper that processes roleOneRoutes and roleTwoRoutes instead and merges their `component` with this kind of wrapper function. And it's much easier if page comp is a shallow wrapper for page contents, all `v-if=role...` conditions can go there

Comment: Would you say the second way its more conventional then? I suppose it would make the routes file a lot cleaner that way instead of doing checks and leaving it to the wrapper to take care of it. On React apps I tend to do the way I mentioned but didn't have an issue like this.

Comment: I believe it's more conventional. There's more than one way to do this, but you won't be able to make a user change a role on relogin without postponing thedecision on role-specific route view component. Would be the same in react too. Also the thing that is specific to vue is that the router starts navigation immediately, before the app is mounted, if you do some async init before app.mount, the router has already started. If you need to fetch some data that the router depends on, this likely has to be done in beforeEach hook