Vue - how to use store using i18n in router.ts
in my router.ts, I need to get a value from one of my store (let's call it storeA). To do that, I did like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77053565/19390218 recommands. So my router looks something like this :
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(useStoreA().myString == "something") {
       next()
    }
})

But my store use i18n in state declaration (not even for myString, but for something else).

import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

export const useStoreA: StoreDefinition<"storeA"> = defineStore(
  "storeA",
  () => {
    const t = useI18n().t;
    const myString="something";
    const myOtherString = t("hey");
})

Thus, this error is raised :
[Vue Router warn]: Unexpected error when starting the router: SyntaxError: Must be called at the top of a 'setup' function because I can not access i18n at this moment, which is weird because in my main.ts, i18n (and pinia) are initialized before the router :
app.use(i18n);
app.use(pinia);
app.use(router);

The error is linked to i18n because the stacktrace point to the line const t = useI18n().t;

I found a workaround by declaring t and myOtherString somewhere else in my store, but it is what it is : a workaround. If anybody has a better solution, it would be well appreciated

The error explains the problem, a composable is expected to be called directly in component setup, unless stated otherwise. This is a regular limitation for composables that results from the implementation of composition API. provide/inject that is commonly used in useI18n and such relies on component hierarchy, which can be established only in component setup.
Pinia store is a notable exception because it doesn't rely on provide/inject.
Therefore it should use DI to use this kind of composables when used iin random places like router hooks, e.g. in root component setup:
store.setI18n(useI18n());

Where setI18n sets i18n value in a store.
Or:
store.init();

Where init calls useI18n and  sets i18n value in a store.
As for i18n, it can be imported directly from the module where it's defined with createI18n instead of using useI18n composable, but this may not apply to other composables.
